# Matlab appeared to install to a nonsensical directory. How to safely undo?

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I just tried to install Matlab on my computer using the normal defaults and I couldn't seem to get it to run. I thought I'd search for the binary file, which is usually called matlab.

```
$ sudo find / -name "matlab"
/root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2016b/archives/common/matlab
/root/Downloads/MathWorks/R2016b/archives/glnxa64/matlab
```

I've never heard of `/root/Downloads`. I guess it tries to install to "Downloads" in whatever directory you tell it to install and since I tried to install as sudo, it just defaulted to making a Downloads directory there. Can I safely delete this `/root/Downloads` folder without destroying my entire system. Is there anything else I need to do to undo this mistake and start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall

```
rm -rf matlabroot
```

Where matlabroot represents the name of your top-level MATLAB installation folder.
I'm guessing the top-level folder would be /root/Downloads/MathWorks.
You may have to sudo the above command.

[Official Uninstall Instructions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/remove-uninstall-mathworks-products.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#bspf_nm-6)